# replacing img source in jquerymobile persistent footer not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

This is a basic navigation implementation where clicking on a button in the jquerymobile navbar swaps the current icon with the "active-state" icon, but this does not seem to be working in my jquerymobile implementation.

code snippet for just turning on the active image is as follows

```
$("#navigation_link").live("click", function(){
    $.mobile.changePage("testpage.php");
    toggleActiveBtn("navigation");
});

function toggleActiveBtn(btnId){

    $("#" + btnId).src = "img/" + btnId + "_active.png";
    /* toggle previously active image to "off" state
    ...
    */
    $("#home).trigger("refresh");
```

HTML in testpage.php is simply:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header" data--position="fixed" data-id="app_header">
    ...
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="main">
    ...
</div>    


<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="app_footer">
    <div data-role="navbar" id="footer_menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="navigation_link" href="javascript:void(0);"><img id="navigation" src="img/navigation.png" /></a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried `$("#home).trigger("create")`, `$("#home").trigger("refresh")` and neither works.

Thanks in advance for the help, folks.

Answer (score 0):

You were doing it correctly, only error was a wrong trigger parameter.

This function:

```
$("#home).trigger("create");
```

only affects page content. To style a whole page (content + header + footer) this function must be used:

```
$("#home).trigger("pagecreate");
```

I made a light example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/yAz8G/

Press button to change a navbar image.